# Compute mean intersection over union with tensorflow op without explicitly calling the update op?

Tags: python, tensorflow

This happens:

```
import tensorflow as tf
labels = tf.constant([1,1,1])
predictions = tf.constant([0,0,1])
miou, conf_mat = tf.metrics.mean_iou(labels, predictions, 2)
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())

miou.eval()
>> 0.0
miou.eval()
>> 0.0

conf_mat.eval()
>> array([[0., 0.],
   [2., 1.]])
miou.eval()
>> 0.16666667
```

It seems that I have to explicitly call the update op (conf_mat) before I can get the mean intersection over union.
Is there a way to compute the result without explicitly calling the update op?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use [`tf.control_depenencies`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/control_dependencies) to force the execution of the `update_op` before the `miou` node:

```
import tensorflow as tf
labels = tf.constant([1, 1, 1])
predictions = tf.constant([0, 0, 1])
miou, conf_mat = tf.metrics.mean_iou(labels, predictions, 2)
with tf.control_dependencies([tf.identity(conf_mat)]):
    miou = tf.identity(miou)
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())

print(miou.eval())
```

Comment: I would strongly advise against silently updating running stats. This is asking for trouble.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I noticed that I still have to call miou.eval() twice before getting a result even with the tf.control_dependency. I'd like to have the result immediately though. Is that possible?

Comment: No it is not, you should change the code of tf.metrics.mean_iou. However as @P-Gn said, this is not a good idea. In general, tf.metrics stats, are running status and thought to be used not in this way (in particular, even my implementation above is not deterministic. Something the output is zero at the first iteration, other times is 0.16666667 - this is the expected behaviour, exactly because this is not the way this stats have to be used)